# Extract values from a string into arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like this:

*john "is my best buddy" and he loves "strawberry juice"*

I want to-

- Extract texts within double-quotes into a string array `array1`
- Split texts outside of double-quotes by spaces and then insert them into another string array (`array2`).

**Output:**

`array1[0]`: is my best buddy

`array1[1]`: strawberry juice

`array2[0]`: john

`array2[1]`: and

`array2[2]`: he

`array2[3]`: loves

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess people might ask what you have tried, and how it failed to do what you want exactly, in order to get better understand of the problem

Comment: Perhaps `string.Split` would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, this is a call for Regular Expressions:

```
var str = @"john ""is my best buddy"" and he loves ""strawberry juice""";

var regex = new Regex("(\"(?'quoted'[^\"]+)\")|(?'word'\\w+)",
                   RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.Compiled);

var matches = regex.Matches(str);

var quotes = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>())
                    .Where(g => g.Name == "quoted" && g.Success)
                    .Select(g => g.Value)
                    .ToArray();

var words = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>())
                    .Where(g => g.Name == "word" && g.Success)
                    .Select(g => g.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```